# How do I Insert/Update a Customer in Dynamics 365 Finance & Operations from an external application

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, integration

How do I from an external c# application insert and/or update a Customer in Dynamics 365 Finance & Operations?

Do I use the OData interface?

Do I use a Azure Service Bus?

Or do I use something else?

Do I need to code something on the Azure side or does existing functionality exist so that I can Create and Update a customer from an external application already?

I need some pointers/example where to read up on how to solve the above problem.
I have read on microsofts site https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/data-entities/odata. But all that information is kinda vague, and there are, i think, alot of ways to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

THere are several ways to do it but a simple and low code would be for example in Azure.
You can create an Azure Logic App that has as a trigger a HTTP Reciever , from  your C# app you can post to this endpoint whatever data you want. You can further transform the data posted there, add conditions and so on... and finally you can use CDS connector to update or insert a record.

Here where you can read more about it:

[LogcApps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/)

[Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-reqres)

[CDS Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/commondataservice/)

Comment: Thank you. I'll look more into the CDS connector.